# Filtering images according to file name, why?

Tags: shell-script, puppy-linux

When filtering the images using the below code, I also need to filter files.

For example,*IMG_0079.JPG.JPG*, when running the code below it's allowing files with additional `.JPG` to get filtered out, and I can't seem to discover why?

- Checking if the input is correct

  ```
  if [ $# != 2 ]; then
     echo "Usage: phar image_path archive_path" && exit;
  fi
  ```
- This will create a destination dir if it doesn't exist

  ```
  mkdir -p $2
  ```
- Statement which finds and copies and adds necessary suffixes to files

  ```
  find $1 -iname IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG -exec cp -b --suffix=.JPG 
  {} $2 \; 
  echo complete!
  ```
- Check and remove duplicate statement. It will compare the md5 of each file.

  ```
      shopt -s nullglob              
      for file in "$2"/* 
      do
        md5sum=$(md5sum < "$file")        
        echo "-- Found: $file ($md5sum)"
        for duplicate in "$2"/*     #loop to find/remove duplicates
        do
          [ "$file" = "$duplicate" ] && continue      
          #comparison of 2 files
          [ "$md5sum" = "$(md5sum < "$duplicate")" ] && rm -v             
          "$duplicate"     
          #removal of duplicates
        done
      done
  ```

Comment: Filter how? What files are you trying to identify and what do you want to do with them? It's not enough to post your script: you also need to tell us what about it you're unhappy with.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop you have mentioned is throwing an error for me. But it works fine when I use escape character for square brackets. So my for loop would be like this:

```
find $1 -iname IMG_\\[0-9\\]\\[0-9\\]\\[0-9\\]\\[0-9\\].JPG -exec cp -b --suffix=.JPG  {} $2 \;
```

Comment: It's working fine both ways for me, however still filtering through duplicates. IMG_0073.JPG & IMG_0073.JPG.JPG. Thats the issue i've came across and cant seem to fix it!

Comment: Have no idea, anyway just give it a try. Give $ at the end of JPG in the find command.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly, your problem lies here:

```
find $1 -iname IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG
```

This never finds the `.JPG.JPG` files in the first place. Look:

```
mkdir JPG
for n in 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
    do touch ./JPG/IMG_000${n}.JPG
done
find ./JPG -iname IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG

###OUTPUT###

./JPG/IMG_0001.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0002.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0003.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0004.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0005.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0006.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0007.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0008.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0009.JPG
```

So now I'll...

```
for f in ./JPG/* ; do touch ${f}.JPG ; done && ls ./JPG

IMG_0001.JPG      IMG_0003.JPG.JPG  IMG_0006.JPG      IMG_0008.JPG.JPG
IMG_0001.JPG.JPG  IMG_0004.JPG      IMG_0006.JPG.JPG  IMG_0009.JPG
IMG_0002.JPG      IMG_0004.JPG.JPG  IMG_0007.JPG      IMG_0009.JPG.JPG
IMG_0002.JPG.JPG  IMG_0005.JPG      IMG_0007.JPG.JPG
IMG_0003.JPG      IMG_0005.JPG.JPG  IMG_0008.JPG
```

Let's see what `find` shows us now:

```
find ./JPG -iname IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG

###OUTPUT###

./JPG/IMG_0001.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0002.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0003.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0004.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0005.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0006.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0007.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0008.JPG
./JPG/IMG_0009.JPG
```

So you see, because my `.JPG.JPG` filenames do not end with the string `[0-9]{4}.JPG` `find` never shows them up in the first place. Adding a `\*` to the end of that `-iname` search string might work better for you.

Still, as the other answer mentions, another problem is your shell globs. For instance:

```
sh -cx 'cd ./JPG ; find . -iname IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG'                                                                      
+ cd ./JPG
+ find . -iname IMG_0001.JPG IMG_0002.JPG IMG_0003.JPG IMG_0004.JPG IMG_0005.JPG IMG_0006.JPG IMG_0007.JPG IMG_0008.JPG IMG_0009.JPG
find: paths must precede expression: IMG_0002.JPG
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

You see? If the shell can it will `[glob]` on those unquoted square brackets you've got before ever even handing the command string to `find`. It should probably look more like this:

```
find "$1" -iname 'IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG*'
```

And regarding the last bit, you might not need to recursively loop so much. I think - so long as you're only looking to remove old `cp --suffix=.JPG -b`ackups - this might do as a workable replacement for everything from `shopt...` on:

```
(   dir=$2
    set -- "${dir}"/*[0-9].???
    while [ -e "$1" ]
    do  cmp "$1" "${1}.JPG" &&
        rm -v "${1}.JPG" 2>&1
    shift ; done
) 2>/dev/null
```

Though, admittedly, that could be optimized a great deal with one *sort of* recursive loop like:

```
(   dir=$2
    set -- "${dir}"/*[0-9].???
    while [ -e "$1" ]
    do  until [ -e "${1}.JPG" ] 
        do shift || break; done
        cmp "$1" "${1}.JPG" &&
        rm -v "${1}.JPG" 2>&1
    ${1+shift} ; done
) 2>/dev/null
```

I say *sort of* because both `while` and `until` loops operate on the same parameter set and never even test the same file twice so they don't exactly *recurse* even if they are nested. Anyway, the optimization lies in not `exec`ing any other process `until` necessary and relying only on shell builtins as much as possible.

Comment: @Joseph - please confirm or deny that this addresses your problem.